# Insert dates in MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, insert, mysql-workbench

I have a error when I try to insert dates with MySql Workbenck

> ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myfacebook`.`mensajes`, CONSTRAINT `CodigoRedDest` FOREIGN KEY (`Codigo`) REFERENCES `redessociales` (`Codigo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO `myfacebook`.`mensajes` (`Codigo`, `NickUsuario`, `CodigoRedDest`, `Mensaje`, `Fecha`) 
VALUES ('7', 'MaGo', '1', 'M7', '2013-09-23')
```

I'm beginner and I don't know what is the problem. If you need more dates about my tables, you say me.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Could you provide us with some information about table redessociales? The message you get it tells you that you cannot add or update a row in a table due to a constraint. I think that should add first a row to the table redessociales and then add your row in 'myfacebook'.'mensajes'

Comment: It's solve. Thans for your  answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to disable the foreign key check with `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
INSERT INTO `myfacebook`.`mensajes` (`Codigo`, `NickUsuario`, `CodigoRedDest`, `Mensaje`, `Fecha`) 
VALUES ('7', 'MaGo', '1', 'M7', '2013-09-23')
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```